# Assigning strtok token to array in struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct, strtok

How would I assign the value from `strtok()` to an array that's in a struct? Inside my struct I have `char *extraRoomOne` and in my main I have:

```
while (token!= NULL)
{ 
    token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    certainRoom.extraRoomOne[counter] = token;
}
```

Compiler is telling me to dereference it, but when I do I get a seg fault.

```
typedef struct room{
    char *extraRoomOne;
}room;
```

In main, all I had was `room certainRoom;

Edit: changed char *extraRoomOne to char **extraRoomOne

Now I have:

```
token = strtok(NULL," ");
certainRoom.extraRoomOne = realloc(certainRoom.extraRoomOne,(counter + 1) * sizeof(char *)); 
certainRoom.extraRoomOne[counter] = malloc(strlen(token)+1);         
strcpy(certainRoom.extraRoomOne[counter],token);`
```

Is this the correct way of realloc and malloc? I increment the counter below each time as well

Comment: Can you please show the declaration of `certainRoom` and the `struct` definition too please.

Comment: Most likely, you should be using `strcpy()` or `strdup()` rather than direct assignment, depending on whether you previously allocated space for `extraRoomOne` to point at.

Comment: And `certainRoom`? is it an array? is it just an instance of `struct room`?

Comment: It is an instance of struct room

Comment: What are you trying to do? because apparently you want to capture many tokens, so how do you want to store them?.

Comment: Im trying to put all the tokens in the room array and then do stuff with it in another function

Answer (score 2):

You should not do that assignment because `strtok()` returns a pointer to the string you passed in the first call and it will change it in subsequent calls, and the `'\0'` terminator can be moved by `strtok()` so the pointer will point to a different string at the end, but instead you can copy the string first allocating space for it with `malloc()` and then with `strcpy()`

```
size_t length;

length                   = strlen(token);
certainRoom.extraRoomOne = malloc(1 + length);
if (certainRoom.extraRoomOne != NULL)
    strcpy(certainRoom.extraRoomOne, token);
```

you should remember to include `string.h`.

And if what you really want is to capture more than just one token, which would explain the `while` loop, you could do it this way

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct room{
    char **tokens;
    size_t count;
} room;

room
tokenizeString(char *string)
{
    char *token;
    room  instance;

    instance.tokens = NULL;
    instance.count        = 0;
    token                    = strtok(string, " ");
    while (token != NULL)
    {
        void  *pointer;
        size_t length;

        pointer = realloc(instance.tokens, (1 + instance.count) * sizeof(char *));
        if (pointer == NULL)
        {
            size_t i;

            for (i = 0 ; i < instance.count ; ++i)
                free(instance.tokens[i]);
            free(instance.tokens);

            instance.tokens = NULL;
            instance.count  = 0;

            return instance;
        }
        instance.tokens                 = pointer;
        length                          = strlen(token);
        instance.tokens[instance.count] = malloc(1 + length);
        if (instance.tokens[instance.count] != NULL)
            strcpy(instance.tokens[instance.count], token);
        instance.count += 1;
        token           = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    return instance;
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    room   certainRoom;
    size_t i;

    if (argc < 1) /* invalid number of arguments */
        return -1;
    certainRoom = tokenizeString(argv[1]);
    for (i = 0 ; i < certainRoom.count ; ++i)
    {
        printf("%s\n", certainRoom.tokens[i]);
        /* we are done working with this token, release it */
        free(certainRoom.tokens[i]);
    }
    /* all tokens where released, now released the main container,
     * note, that this only contained the pointers, the data was
     * in the space pointed to by these pointers. */
    free(certainRoom.tokens);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried the realloc,malloc before I copy it but now i'm getting a segfault, could you check if im doing it right? I edited it above

Comment: @BeginnerC96 use the code I proposed because doing this `x = realloc(x, newSize);` is bad practice, `realloc()` to a different pointer so you can handle failure, and don't ignore the return value of `malloc()`. Although, the `SIGSEGV` must be cause by something else probably, it depends on the size of the string, or how you use the tokens after tokenizing the string.